# how to updates recycler view elements from onActivityResult

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, onactivityresult

I have a problem with updates my recyclerView. When I get unswer (it`s ArrayList with objects) in method onActivityResult I call the custom update method, where I update my ArrayList, but nothing happens...
I try to do it like in this topic [how to update RecyclerView element from OnActivityResult](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37632957/how-to-update-recyclerview-element-from-onactivityresult)

It`s my code :

Parent`s activity :

```
ArrayList<Unswer> unswerFromMain;

@Override

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    //super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (data==null){
        Log.d("LOGO", "no unswer" );
        return;
    } else {


        unswerFromMain = (ArrayList<Unswer>) data.getSerializableExtra("aboutGROUPS");

        recyclerAdapter.updateAdapter(unswerFromMain);

    }

}
```

}

RecyclerAdapter class :

```
private ArrayList<Unswer> getUnswer = new ArrayList<>();

public void updateAdapter (ArrayList<Unswer> updateUnswer){

    getUnswer = updateUnswer;

    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Comment: at what point are you setting the recyclerviews adapter and how do you update the data of the adapter?

Comment: I setting custom View, which contain 3 TextView and 1 ImageButton.When somebody tap to ImageButton - start method startActivityForResult from adapter. After you changes field I update it. Updating start in method onActivityResult when I call method updateAdapter and put my new ArrayList

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
getUnswer.clear()
getUnswer.addAll(updateUnswer);
```

instead of

```
getUnswer = updateUnswer;
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I add this changes and it works!

Comment: Glad to be of help