# How can I add results from textView in android studio?

Tags: android, android-activity, textview

Here is my code :

```java
if(radioButton_correct1e.isChecked()) {
     score++;
     scoreText.setText(Integer.toString(score));
}
```

the result is then shown in textView. This is the same for activity A & B . So how can i add results for both activities and show in activity C?

Comment: Use an Intent to start a new activity with parameters

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18146745/4402462

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(ActivityAB.this, ActivityC.class);
intent.putExtra("score",score);
startActivity(intent);
```

And to get it in `ActivityC` in `onCreate`.

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
int score = intent.getIntExtra("score",0);
```