# How to use 3 different Activities variables into another new activity?

Tags: java, android

For example:

```
int a=5;  //in MainActivity.java
int b=7 //in MainActivity2.java
int c=8 //in MainActivity3.java
```

and these three variables in another Activity i.e.

```
int total= a+b+c  //in MainActivity4.java
```

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: as per my requirement in the code @AbdulWaheed

Comment: you can do this via passing intent to the activity and pass these variable in intent and get those to other activity

Comment: how? @AbdulWaheed

Comment: see my answer below

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to send string from one activity to another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18146614/how-to-send-string-from-one-activity-to-another)

Comment: This is a very bad question. I'm assuming you are a junior engineer. I'd recommend you spend the next few days going through Android's architecture guidelines / samples in depth. It'd be worth it for you to follow it almost exactly for the time being. https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/index.html

Comment: SharedPrefence or sending it with a intent.

Comment: Okay, you can simply use **public static variable** but you should inform us of your intention. There might be better solutions.

Comment: @spierce7 yes I am junior and thank you for the guidance :)

Comment: @H.Brooks thanks :)

Comment: @programmer1 its basically food menu and calculating total bill

Comment: @GowthamanM thanks :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As mentioned in your code you are using

```
int a=5;  //in MainActivity.java
int b=7 //in MainActivity2.java
int c=8 //in MainActivity3.java
```

To start activity you must be using below code

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, yourRequiredActivity.class)
intent .putExtra("firstVariable", a);
intent .putExtra("secondVariable", b);
intent .putExtra("thirdVariable", c);
startActivity(myIntent);
```

And when new Activity starts use below code

```
 Intent mIntent = getIntent();
 int a= mIntent.getIntExtra("firstVariable", 0);
 int b= mIntent.getIntExtra("secondVariable", 0);
 int c= mIntent.getIntExtra("thirdVariable", 0);
```

And now you can use below code for your operation

```
int total= a+b+c
```

hope that answers your question.

Comment: This is the best answer, you can also include that SharedPreferences could also be a option.

Comment: This is probably the best answer so far, however, this is very difficult to maintain as well. I'd recommend you store the data outside of intents and activity's in memory. SharedPreferences would also be valid.

Comment: Who is downvoting this answer? please mention the reason so I can update my answer.

Comment: @Leenaharani I am glad that helped you :)

Answer (score -1):

way 1: you can use public static variable.but static variable is memory leak.

```
public static int a=5;  //in MainActivity.java
public static int b=7 //in MainActivity2.java
public static int c=8 //in MainActivity3.java  


int total= a+b+c  //in MainActivity4.java
```

way 2: other way, save a,b,c in shared preference and in MainActivity4.java load there and use.

Comment: what is shared preference? and how can we do it?

Comment: "static variable is memory leak", That's misleading. It can be used to leak memory, but it's not necessarily a memory leak.

Answer (score -1):

You can just make those variables `static`, and can access them from `MainActivity4`. If you want to make these variables `private` and write protected, then use a static getter method.