# How to pass and get value in public class?

Tags: android, android-studio

I have a java class and here is the code

```
public class credentials {

    public static String getName(String name) {
        String name1 = name;
        return name1;
    }

}
```

Heres how I pass a value

`credentials.getName("Sample Name");`

my prob here is how can i get that value

How can I get the value that i passed from another classes?

Its like im passing it using another activity and I need to get it from another

Comment: and where to pass value ??

Comment: for example on another activity

Comment: paste your code

Comment: done editing my qiestion

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to send string from one activity to another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18146614/how-to-send-string-from-one-activity-to-another)

Comment: Ive seen that duplicate post but my question is different. I want to get using different activity. so u mean i need to pass value everythime another activity will get it?

Comment: ya you send the data activity to another activity

Comment: The `getName` method just returns its parameter, pretty useless. It is not clear what you want to achieve with it.

Comment: @MohammadAli it has to be one activity to all

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/

Comment: @Henry like for example something like this `string name = credentials.getname();`

Comment: it also possible using duplicate question @myownemail

Comment: Seems you want a class with a field `name` and a getter and a setter method. However, still not clear how this would help to transfer values between activities because you would need to obtain a reference to this object first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to send data from one activity to another then you can send it through intent.

**FirstActivity**, sending data to SecondActivity through intent.

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(FirstActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("Credential","your credential");
    startActivity(intent);
```

**SecondActivity**, receiving data from Firstactivity.

```
    String getCredential = getIntent().getStringExtra("Credential");
```

**Or**

Just create a Model class and make them all the variables and methods static, so It can be accessed without an object of Model class.

```
public class Model{

    public static String name;

    public static String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public static void setName(String xName) {
          name = xName;
    }
}
```

**FirstActivity**

```
 Model.setName("opriday");
```

**SecondActivity**

```
 String getName = Model.getName();
```

Comment: the second one fits my need tysm

Comment: Happy to help you :) best of luck

Answer (score 0):

> This is a very basic example use to show how to pass data from one activity to another(here I use Shareprefrence)

```
     --------------------------Activity1-----------------------------------------  

             editText1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.ed1);
            editText2=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.ed2);
            but=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn);
            sp=getSharedPreferences("mypref",MODE_PRIVATE);

            but.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    String s=editText1.getText().toString();
                    String s1=editText2.getText().toString();



                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor=sp.edit();

                    editor.putString("user",s);
                    editor.putString("id",s1);
                    editor.commit();
                    gotomainactivity();


                }
            });

            String userId=sp.getString("user",null);
            String password=sp.getString("id",null);
            if(userId!=null && password!=null){
                gotomainactivity();
            }

        }

        private void gotomainactivity() {
            Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,Sharedatarecive.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------Activity2------------ 

// receive data from activity1

     sep=getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("mypref",MODE_PRIVATE);
            TextView textView=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.t1);
            TextView textView1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.t2);

            String s3=sep.getString("user",null);
            String s4=sep.getString("id",null);

    //display data in anctivity2


            textView.setText(s3);
            textView1.setText(s4);
```

Comment: Why would someone use SharedPreferences to pass data between activities? That's not what SP is intended for