# Transfer image to other activity in kotlin

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

I am making an application like instagram which will allow the user to upload their pic and if they need any editing then they can press editing button and they can edit. How can I transfer the same photo which the user chose to the editing activity in kotlin? And also after editing how can I covert the whole ConstraintLayout to image and transfer it back to the upload activity.

Comment: I would recommend to stick to the new model android provides, 1 activity and fragments. This way you can save the image to activity viewmodel and retrieve it inside of the fragment.

Comment: But I have not made it with fragment

Answer (score 0):

You can save the image to internal storage from activity one, then send the image name to the second activity (via `Intent`) and open it in second activity.

1. Save the image to internal storage:

   `saveToInternalStorage(context, <your_bitmap>, <image_name>)`
2. Start activity like in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18146745/8835675) and instead of `message` put <image_name>
3. On opened activity, get your <image_name>
4. Open the image from internal storage:

   `val bitmap = getImageFromInternalStorage(context, <image_name>)`

Here is my storage helper class:

```
class ImageStorageManager {
    companion object {
        fun saveToInternalStorage(context: Context, bitmapImage: Bitmap, imageFileName: String): String {
            context.openFileOutput(imageFileName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE).use { fos ->
                bitmapImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 50, fos)
            }
            return context.filesDir.absolutePath
        }

        fun getImageFromInternalStorage(context: Context, imageFileName: String): Bitmap? {
            val directory = context.filesDir
            val file = File(directory, imageFileName)
            return if (file.exists()) {
                BitmapFactory.decodeStream(FileInputStream(file))
            } else {
                null
            }
        }

        fun deleteImageFromInternalStorage(context: Context, imageFileName: String): Boolean {
            val dir = context.filesDir
            val file = File(dir, imageFileName)
            return file.delete()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sir actually I am a beginner and I have less knowledge about it. Can u explain me properly like how will I do

Comment: I've added some more details for you.

Comment: Thank you sir for ur help. Sir if u do not mind can u answer one more question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62726564/profile-fragment-code-not-working-in-kotlin

Comment: Mark this one as accepted if it helped you achieve your goal.