# Profile fragment code not working in kotlin

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I making my profile fragment and I want to display the post and the number of post in the Profile of the app. I have searched for the code from websites and I wrote this codes but this codes are not working.
Here is my code

```
class ProfileFragment : Fragment() {
    var fragmentView: View? = null
    var firestore: FirebaseFirestore? = null
    var uid: String? = null
    var auth: FirebaseAuth? = null
    var currentUserUid: String? = null

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        fragmentView = LayoutInflater.from(activity).inflate(R.layout.fragment_profile,container,false)
        uid = arguments?.getString("destinationUid")
        firestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
        auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
        currentUserUid = auth?.currentUser?.uid
        fragmentView?.account_reyclerview?.adapter = UserFragmentRecyclerviewAdapter()
        fragmentView?.account_reyclerview?.layoutManager = GridLayoutManager(activity, 3)
        return fragmentView
    }
    inner class UserFragmentRecyclerviewAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>(){
        var contentDTOs:ArrayList<ContentDTO> = arrayListOf()
        init {
            firestore?.collection("images")?.whereEqualTo("uid",uid)?.addSnapshotListener{querySnapshot, firebaseFirestoreException ->
                if (querySnapshot ==null){
                    return@addSnapshotListener
                }
                for (snapshot in querySnapshot.documents){
                    snapshot.toObject(ContentDTO::class.java)?.let { contentDTOs.add(it) }
                }
                fragmentView?.account_tv_post_count?.text = contentDTOs.size.toString()
                notifyDataSetChanged()
            }
        }

        override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, p0: Int): RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
            var width = resources.displayMetrics.widthPixels/3
            var imageView = ImageView(parent.context)
            imageView.layoutParams = LinearLayoutCompat.LayoutParams(width,width)
            return CustomViewHolder(imageView)
        }

        inner class CustomViewHolder(var imageview: ImageView) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(imageview) {

        }

        override fun getItemCount(): Int {
            return contentDTOs.size
        }

        override fun onBindViewHolder(p0: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, p1: Int) {
            var imageview = (p0 as CustomViewHolder).imageview
            Glide.with(p0.itemView.context).load(contentDTOs[p1].imageUrl).apply(RequestOptions().centerCrop()).into(imageview)
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: are you sure you are getting data from firebase? also it could be layout problem because of too big of a image.

Comment: Sir can u plz explain it properly like where is the mistake and how can I correct it. Also I want to display the post in the profile fragment which is not working