# How do I pass and get an String value from different activity?

Tags: android

The scenario I have now is, I am going to start 2 activity to get some String value, then on the 3rd activity, I will capture the String value and then I will compare the captured String and change the image source

example:

1. choose programme
2. choose day (monday~friday)
3. captured the String pass from programme to day, and combine both and pass to activity with ImageView

**once again i have edited the code.**

1st activity

```
enter code here

public class TestSchedule extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_test_schedule);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.test_schedule, menu);
    return true;
}

public void SSD(View view){
    String programme = "SSD";
    Intent intent = new Intent(TestSchedule.this,TextDay.class);
    intent.putExtra("prog", programme);
    startActivity(intent);
    }

public void EIS(View view){
    String programme = "EIS";
    Intent intent = new Intent(TestSchedule.this,TextDay.class);
    intent.putExtra("prog", programme);
    startActivity(intent);
    }

public void IS(View view){
    String programme = "IS";
    Intent intent = new Intent(TestSchedule.this,TextDay.class);
    intent.putExtra("prog", programme);
    startActivity(intent);
    }

public void IT(View view){
    String programme = "IT";
    Intent intent = new Intent(TestSchedule.this,TextDay.class);
    intent.putExtra("prog", programme);
    startActivity(intent);
    }

}
```

2nd activity

```
public class TextDay extends Activity {

String programme;

private void getData(){
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if(extras != null){
        programme = extras.getString("prog");
    }
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_text_day);
    getData();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.text_day, menu);
    return true;
}

public void monday(View view){
    if(programme.equals("SSD")){
        String programDay = "SSDMon";
        Intent intent = new Intent(TextDay.this, TestShow.class);
        intent.putExtra("progDay", programDay);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    if(programme.equals("EIS")){
        String programDay = "EISMon";
        Intent intent = new Intent(TextDay.this, TestShow.class);
        intent.putExtra("progDay", programDay);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    if(programme.equals("IS")){
        String programDay = "ISMon";
        Intent intent = new Intent(TextDay.this, TestShow.class);
        intent.putExtra("progDay", programDay);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    if(programme.equals("IT")){
        String programDay = "ITMon";
        Intent intent = new Intent(TextDay.this, TestShow.class);
        intent.putExtra("progDay", programDay);
        startActivity(intent);
    }   
    }
}
```

3rd activity which will capture and change the image source

```
enter code here

public class TestShow extends Activity {

ImageView image;
String table;

private void getData(){
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if(extras != null){
        table = extras.getString("progDay");
    }
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_test_show);
    getData();
    image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.showTimeTable);
    if(table.equals("SSDMonday")){
        image.setImageResource(R.drawable.ssd_mon);
    }
    if(table.equals("EISMonday")){
        image.setImageResource(R.drawable.eis_mon);
    }
    if(table.equals("ISMonday")){
        image.setImageResource(R.drawable.is_mon);
    }
    if(table.equals("ITMonday")){
        image.setImageResource(R.drawable.it_mon);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.test_show, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

Comment: what you tried yet ??

Comment: wait a minute, i have deleted my code just now. i need to retype

Comment: sorry i am still new to this place. 1st time posting. sorry if duplicate. and i have uploaded my code. i am still new to android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually the solution for this is to put the String as a extra to the intent and together with this extra string send the intent to the other activity

Check this link for more details on how to implement this : 
[Pass a String from one Activity to another Activity in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6707900/how-to-pass-string-one-activity-to-another)

ANSWER IN THE COMMENTS SECTION.

Comment: i have take a look at the code, where should i get the intent? during onCreate?

Comment: I think Jgdsh Seerm's answer is really clear and should be the explanation for your question. (:

Comment: i have just updated the code i am using now. could you take a look? becuase i dint know how the send picture work. coz i am going change the image using the string i get from activity 1 and 2. then combine them 2 and compare at the last activity and change the image in my drawable with the same string

Comment: Instead of calling Intent i = getIntent() at the top as a variable, you should create a new method maybe called private void getData() { Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if (extras != null) { programme = extras.getString("prog");
    if(programme.equals("SSD")){ ....
....
Then you call the method getData in your OnCreate method of your TestDay Class.

Comment: i have tired what you teach me, it dint give me errors, but the image dint change.

Comment: check my code. i have edit it base on what you taught me.

Comment: Hi whats the error you are seeing now? Is it still nullpointer at the 2nd activity?

Comment: 2nd acitivity dint give me nullpointer but it dint change the image resource as i have changed it in 3rd activity with the if else. now i dont know whether is the string put successful or not. or is the reading got problem.

Comment: the things you taught me is workable, just my silly mistake, i set wrong progday. anyway thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use bundle when starting new activity

```
Bundle b = new Bundle;
```

> b.putString(s,key);
>   intent.putExtra(b);
>   startActivity(intent);

More:
http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidIntent/article.html

Answer (score 0):

Like this

Sending activity ActivityA

```
Intent newActivity1 = new Intent(ActivityA.this, ActivityB.class);
newActivity1.putExtra("choose_programme", position);
startActivity(newActivity1);
```

Receiving Activity ActivityB

```
String value = getIntent().getExtras().getString("choose_programme");
```

Comment: actually i have no idea with the argument that i should put. like putExtra(?, ?) what is the 1st and 2nd parameter for?

Comment: First parameter is KEY, second parameter values you want to pass. ex : i want to pass MONDAY (string) to activityB :  newActivity1.putExtra("days", "MONDAY"); you can get that value in activityB like this : String value = getIntent().getExtras().getString("days"); fell free to ask if are not clear still

Comment: i just figured it out while looking at 1 of the answer below. anyway thanks, still trying

Comment: thx for the answer, i have finally able to do it.

Answer (score 0):

1 Send the Image to the next Activity...You can send the Bitmap because it implements Parcelable

```
private void sendImage() {
  //Getting the Bitmap from the imageView
  BitmapDrawable drawable = (BitmapDrawable) imageView.getDrawable(); 
  Bitmap bitmap = drawable.getBitmap();

  Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, NextActivity.class);
  intent.putExtra("PROGRAMME", "PROGRAMME_VALUE");
  intent.putExtra("DAY", "DAY_VALUE");
  intent.putExtra("IMAGE", bitmap);
  startActivity(intent);
}
```

2 Get the image in the NextActivity

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if (extras != null) {
   // Bitmap
   Bitmap image = (Bitmap) extras.get("IMAGE");
   if (image != null) {
     imageView.setImageBitmap(image);
   }
   // String value
   String programmeValue = intent.getString("PROGRAMME");
   String dayValue = intent.getString("DAY");
}
```

Comment: actually i have implemented the image in my drawable, i just want to get programme as in string and day in string, so i could know which day and which programme. and i will use if else to open for different png in my imageview. and i still need the bitmap? i couldnt understand how the bundle and bitmap do.

Comment: since i am having 3 activity. can i do it this way? i declare 2 intent, which is ii and intent. then i do ii.putExtra() this will put extra straight to the 3rd activity, then i startActivity(intent) which only start the activity2. so i can put another string from activity2 to activity3. and finally i capture all 2 intent?