# android - how to set text from object

Tags: java, android, class, object, textview

i got class Team and object name. I want to display the name in another activity in textView and i don't know how to do it. Can you help me?
my code of class and object:

```
public class DruzynyStatActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
public class Team
{
    public String name;


}
```

...

```
public void cracovia(View view)
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, CracoviaActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    Team cracovia= new Team();
    cracovia.name="Cracovia";
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to pass string one activity to another?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6707900/how-to-pass-string-one-activity-to-another)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the data over the intents.
The code you are using on the button click is starting the next activity with passing parameter as intent.

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(this, CracoviaActivity.class);
 intent.putExtra("key","value");
 startActivity(intent);
```

Now on the another activity you can get this intent and the value by the key.
as-

```
  Intent intent=getIntent()
  String received_value=intent.getStringExtra("key");
```

You can also add a Bundle object on the intent if you want to deal with more no of data.

Comment: thanks a lot everyone! and after i pass data how to display it in text view?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `putExtra(..., ...)` to pass values between activities.

See [this other StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5265913/how-to-use-putextra-and-getextra-for-string-data)

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
public void cracovia(View view)
{
  Intent intent = new Intent(this, CracoviaActivity.class);
  Team cracovia= new Team();
  cracovia.name="Cracovia";
  name = cracovia.name;
  intent.putExtra("teamName", name);
  startActivity(intent);

}
```

Unless I am misunderstanding.