# After get the data on the server need to pass to another view in android studio

Tags: android

[image]

THis is the result i get after i login to the server. the main things i want to do is, after it login and will open another page which will list out all the data to another activity named MainActivity.

```
public void showJSON(String json){
    ParseJson pj = new ParseJson(json);
    pj.parseJson();
    EventList cl = new EventList(this, ParseJson.ids,ParseJson.titles,ParseJson.descriptions);
    listViewMain.setAdapter(cl);
}
```

I try to put this code inside my MainActivity, and called it from LoginActivity:

```
public void onResponse(String response) {
                        if(response.trim().equals("Login failed. Please enter the correct information.")){
                            Toast.makeText(Login.this, response, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        }else{
                            MainActivity test = new MainActivity();
                            test.showJSON(response);
                        }
                    }
```

But it got the error which is no responding. The main purpose is i want to get the data and put into my MainActivity listview. What method should i try after login and get the data in my another activity.

Comment: Have you referred http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6707900/pass-a-string-from-one-activity-to-another-activity-in-android ?

Comment: ya, but it doesnot show me about the data passing

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is correct, get the data in login activity and then pass it to Main activity using intent
With intent.putextra, you can set your data and call your next activity. 
For details see below link.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html

Comment: Thanks, i am quite new in this area. So this make me confuse.

Comment: No prob, just keep the list in main activity and you can pass data as mentioned above.

Comment: So put the showJSON inside mainactivity is ok? But the data doesnot pass into the Mainactivity and cause it fail

Comment: `public void parseData(String json){
//        Toast.makeText(Login.this, json, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("data",json);
        startActivity(intent);
    }` Is that what you mean?