# How to pass string from one activity to another

Tags: java, android

I want to pass string from one activity to another.In the second activity the string should be readable.

```
listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
First actvity code
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,
                                long id) {

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            Intent dash_des = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Dashboard_Description__page.class);

           //here should be t my string


        }
    });
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_dashboard__description__page);

        //here i want to read the string data
        }
```

Comment: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6707900/pass-a-string-from-one-activity-to-another-activity-in-android

Answer (score 2):

You should probably read about Intents in Android.

You can achieve this by using:

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(FirstActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);
myIntent.putExtra("TestString","TestValue");
startActivity(myIntent);
```

The above code will launch SecondActivity. Now in onCreate() of second activity you need to:

```
String stringCameFromFirstAcvitity = getIntent().getStringExtra("TestString");
```

The value of stringCameFromFirstAcvitity will be "TestValue"

In your case

```
listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
//First actvity code
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,
                            long id) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Intent dash_des = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Dashboard_Description__page.class);
    Object obj = listview.getAdapter().getItem(position);
    String value = obj.toString();
    dash_des .putExtra("TestString",value);
    startActivity(dash_des );
    }
});

 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_dashboard__description__page);

    //here i want to read the string data
    }
```

Code for secondActivity remains same. Hope it helps

Comment: i need TestValue as  dynamic value which i clicked

Comment: I am editing my answer accordingly

Comment: I am very new to coding.. i want to get value of bookmark_title.. not poistion.

Comment: Yes you are right, it is not taking the position, it is taking the item at the position and getting the name of that item and writing it. Is that not working? what is the output that you are getting and what do you expect, please post here.

Comment: i am gettng this output com.example.compy.project_app.Actors@b4e65fa8

Comment: and i am excpection website, title, id, etc parameters please

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent dash_des = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Dashboard_Description__page.class);

dash_des.putString("your_key", your_string_variable);
startActivity(dash_des);
```

**In second activity:**

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
String text = bundle.getString("your_key");
```

Answer (score 0):

When there are multiple strings that u need to pass from one activity to another its always a best practice to bundle them and pass it to the next activity.
Something like this:

```
Intent in = new Intent(Firstactivity.this, Secondactivity.class);
    Bundle mbundle = new Bundle();
    mbundle.putString("name", name);
    mbundle.putString("phonenumber", phonenumber);
    in.putExtras(mbundle);
```

And they same can be retrieved from the secondactivity as follows,

```
 Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
 String name= bundle.getString("name");
 String phoneNumber= bundle.getString("phonenumber");
```

Comment: how to pass phonenumber

Comment: you can pass any datatype via intents. Suppose your phonenumber is in integer format you can  do mbundle.putInt("phonenumber",phonenumber);

Answer (score 0):

In the intent put the extring as extra..

and then hold it back in the activity2

## Example:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(current.this, Activity2.class);
intent.putExtra("key","value");
startActivity(intent);
```

in the Activity2:

```
String data = getIntent().getExtras().getString("key");
```

Comment: String data = getIntent().getExtras().getString("key");
        System.out.println(data);
this gives me error

Comment: what error do you get?