# Passing ListView String data to Third Activity

Tags: listview, android-edittext, settext

I have three activity, my first activity is of ListView. Clicking ListView it goes to second Activity. And second activity leads to edittext of third activity. i want to get Listview string to third activity into an if else statement as if it is an user input.

```
if (number<=99 )
{
    txt.setText("STD অনলাইন নাম্বারঃ\n" + (I want first Activity Listview String here) "0040000" +etx.getText());
}
```

How can i get it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pass a String from one Activity to another Activity in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6707900/pass-a-string-from-one-activity-to-another-activity-in-android)

Comment: No, It is not. I want String Array of First Activity to Third activity, though OnItemClickListener leads to second activity.please tell me if ther is any way. Devendra Singh

Comment: Although you can pass the array to second and than second to third activity.

Comment: Thinking so.I tried bundle and extra.but not working.

Comment: What error you are getting?

Comment: I Started doing it another way. you were cooperative.Thanks @ Devendra Singh