# ListView Not Displaying in New Activity

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I am trying to get a ListView to appear in a new activity. I can see the record ID in the logcat, and I can see that the proper ID is being selected in debug view, but when I go to the new activity the list array is empty.

This is what I am seeing in debug view:

[image: debug view]

In the **logcat** I see this:

```
2018-10-07 11:39:09.286 12624-12624/ca.rvogl.tpbcui D/SAVEDLEAGUEID_VAL: 1
2018-10-07 11:39:09.286 12624-12624/ca.rvogl.tpbcui D/LEAGUEID_VAL: android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView{e67a170 G.ED..... ......I. 0,0-0,0 #7f080112 app:id/tvLeagueId}
2018-10-07 11:39:09.293 12624-12624/ca.rvogl.tpbcui D/GETALLBOWLERS-SQL: SQL used = >>>>SELECT  * FROM bowlers WHERE league_id = '1' ORDER BY timestamp DESC<<<<
2018-10-07 11:39:09.298 12624-12624/ca.rvogl.tpbcui D/GETALLBOWLERS-CNT: Number of rows retrieved = 0
2018-10-07 11:39:09.299 12624-12624/ca.rvogl.tpbcui D/GETALLBOWLERS-CNT: Number of elements in bowlerslist = 0
```

As you can see from the logcat the savedLeagueId is being passed to the SQLite Query that is suppose to be getting the list of Bowlers for the listview.  However the number of elements in the bowlerslist is 0.

I have gone through the code over and over again but I am unable to isolate where the issue is.

**LeagueAdapter.java**

```
public class LeagueAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<LeagueAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    private Context context;
    private List<League> leaguesList;

    public void notifyDatasetChanged(List<League> newleagueslist) {
        leaguesList.clear();
        leaguesList.addAll(newleagueslist);
        super.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView name;
        public TextView basescore;
        public TextView basescorepercentage;
        public TextView id;
        public TextView wins;
        public TextView losses;
        public TextView timestamp;
        public TextView buttonViewOption;

        public MyViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            id = view.findViewById( R.id.tvLeagueId);
            name = view.findViewById(R.id.tvSeriesName );
            basescore = view.findViewById(R.id.tvBaseScore );
            basescorepercentage = view.findViewById(R.id.tvBaseScorePercentage );
            wins = view.findViewById(R.id.tvLeagueWins );
            losses = view.findViewById(R.id.tvLeagueLosses );
            timestamp = view.findViewById(R.id.timestamp);
            buttonViewOption = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.buttonViewOptions);
        }
    }


    public LeagueAdapter(Context context, List<League> leaguesList) {

        this.context = context;
        this.leaguesList = leaguesList;
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.listview_league, parent, false);

        return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {

        League league = leaguesList.get(position);
        int id = league.getId();
        Log.d("id", String.valueOf(id));
        int leagueId = id;
        Log.d("leagueId", String.valueOf(leagueId));
        holder.id.setText(String.valueOf(leagueId));
        holder.name.setText(league.getName());
        holder.basescore.setText(league.getBaseScore());
        holder.basescorepercentage.setText(league.getBaseScorePercentage());

        holder.wins.setText(league.getWins());
        holder.losses.setText(league.getLosses());
        /*if (league.getAverage() != "") {
            holder.leagueAverage.setText(String.format("League Avg: %s", league.getAverage()));
        } else {
            holder.leagueAverage.setText(String.format("League Avg: %s", "0"));
        }*/
        //Formatting And Displaying Timestamp
        holder.timestamp.setText(formatDate(league.getTimestamp()));
        holder.buttonViewOption.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                //creating a popup menu
                PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(context, holder.buttonViewOption);
                //inflating menu from xml resource
                popup.inflate(R.menu.league_options_menu);
                //adding click listener
                popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                        switch (item.getItemId()) {
                            case R.id.profile:
                                Log.d("leagueId", String.valueOf(position));
                                int leagueId = league.getId();
                                String savedLeagueId = String.valueOf(id);
                                Intent myIntent = new Intent(context, LeagueProfileViewActivity.class);
                                myIntent.putExtra("leagueId", leagueId);
                                context.startActivity(myIntent);
                                break;
                            case R.id.delete:
                                ((MainActivity) context).deleteLeague(position);
                                break;
                        }
                        return false;
                    }
                });
                //displaying the popup
                popup.show();

            }
        });
        holder.name.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //String leagueId = String.valueOf(leaguesList.get(position).getId());

                int leagueId = league.getId();
                String savedLeagueId = String.valueOf(id);
                Log.d("leagueId", String.valueOf(position));
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(context, BowlerActivity.class);
                myIntent.putExtra("leagueId", savedLeagueId);
                context.startActivity(myIntent);

            }
        });
    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return leaguesList.size();
    }

    //Formatting TimeStamp to 'EEE MMM dd yyyy (HH:mm:ss)'
    //Input  : 2018-05-23 9:59:01
    //Output : Wed May 23 2018 (9:59:01)
    private String formatDate(String dateStr) {
        try {
            SimpleDateFormat fmt = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
            Date date = fmt.parse(dateStr);
            SimpleDateFormat fmtOut = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd yyyy (HH:mm:ss)");
            return fmtOut.format(date);
        } catch (ParseException e) {

        }

        return "";
    }
}
```

I am moving to the BowlerActivity using holder.name, where I am passing the League ID using an intent.

**BowlerActivity.java**

```
public class BowlerActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private BowlerAdapter mAdapter;
    private final List<Bowler> bowlersList = new ArrayList<>();
    private TextView noBowlersView;

    private DatabaseHelper db;

    private TextView leagueId;
    private String savedLeagueId;

    /*private TextView seriesleagueId;
    private String seriesLeagueId;
    private TextView bowlerAverage;
    private TextView bowlerHandicap;
    private String savedBowlerAverage;*/


    private static final String PREFS_NAME = "prefs";
    private static final String PREF_BLUE_THEME = "blue_theme";
    private static final String PREF_GREEN_THEME = "green_theme";
    private static final String PREF_ORANGE_THEME = "purple_theme";
    private static final String PREF_RED_THEME = "red_theme";
    private static final String PREF_YELLOW_THEME = "yellow_theme";


    @Override protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        db = new DatabaseHelper( this );

        mAdapter.notifyDatasetChanged( db.getAllBowlers(savedLeagueId ) );
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        //Use Chosen Theme
        SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences( PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE );
        boolean useBlueTheme = preferences.getBoolean( PREF_BLUE_THEME, false );
        if (useBlueTheme) {
            setTheme( R.style.AppTheme_Blue_NoActionBar );
        }
        boolean useGreenTheme = preferences.getBoolean( PREF_GREEN_THEME, false );
        if (useGreenTheme) {
            setTheme( R.style.AppTheme_Green_NoActionBar );
        }
        boolean useOrangeTheme = preferences.getBoolean( PREF_ORANGE_THEME, false );
        if (useOrangeTheme) {
            setTheme( R.style.AppTheme_Orange_NoActionBar );
        }
        boolean useRedTheme = preferences.getBoolean( PREF_RED_THEME, false );
        if (useRedTheme) {
            setTheme( R.style.AppTheme_Red_NoActionBar );
        }
        boolean useYellowTheme = preferences.getBoolean( PREF_YELLOW_THEME, false );
        if (useYellowTheme) {
            setTheme( R.style.AppTheme_Yellow_NoActionBar );
        }

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_bowler);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        Objects.requireNonNull( getSupportActionBar() ).setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);

        toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class));
                finish();
                overridePendingTransition(0, 0);

            }
        });

        savedLeagueId = String.valueOf(getIntent().getStringExtra("leagueId"));
        leagueId = findViewById(R.id.tvLeagueId);
        Log.d("SAVEDLEAGUEID_VAL", String.valueOf(savedLeagueId));
        Log.d("LEAGUEID_VAL", String.valueOf(leagueId));
        /*bowlerAverage = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvBowlerAverage);

                bowlerHandicap = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvBowlerHandicap);*/

        CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout = findViewById( R.id.coordinator_layout );
        RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById( R.id.recycler_view );
        noBowlersView = findViewById(R.id.empty_bowlers_view);

        db = new DatabaseHelper(this);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.add_bowler_fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //showBowlerDialog(false, null, -1);
                boolean shouldUpdate = false;
                int bowlerId = -1;
                String leagueId = String.valueOf(savedLeagueId);
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), BowlerProfileEditActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("shouldUpdate", shouldUpdate);
                intent.putExtra("leagueId", leagueId);
                intent.putExtra("bowlerId", bowlerId);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
                overridePendingTransition(0, 0);

            }
        });

        mAdapter = new BowlerAdapter(this, bowlersList);
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        toggleEmptyBowlers();
    }

    //Inserting New Bowler In The Database And Refreshing The List
    private void createBowler(String leagueId, String bowlerName) {
        String bowlerAverage = "0";
        //Inserting Bowler In The Database And Getting Newly Inserted Bowler Id
        long id = db.insertBowler(savedLeagueId, bowlerName, bowlerAverage);

        //Get The Newly Inserted Bowler From The Database
        Bowler n = db.getBowler(savedLeagueId);

        if (n != null) {
            //Adding New Bowler To The Array List At Position 0
            bowlersList.add( 0, n );
            //Refreshing The List
            mAdapter.notifyDatasetChanged(db.getAllBowlers(savedLeagueId));
            //mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            toggleEmptyBowlers();
        }
    }

    //Updating Bowler In The Database And Updating The Item In The List By Its Position
    private void updateBowler(String bowlerName, int position) {
        Bowler n = bowlersList.get(position);

        //Updating Bowler Text
        n.setLeagueId(savedLeagueId);
        n.setName(bowlerName);

        //Updating The Bowler In The Database
        db.updateBowler(n);

        //Refreshing The List
        bowlersList.set(position, n);
        mAdapter.notifyItemChanged(position);

        toggleEmptyBowlers();
    }

    //Deleting Bowler From SQLite Database And Removing The Bowler Item From The List By Its Position
    public void deleteBowler(int position) {

        Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(findViewById(android.R.id.content), "Series will be deleted.", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                .setActionTextColor(Color.YELLOW)
                .setAction("OK", new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        //Deleting The Bowler From The Database
                        db.deleteBowler(bowlersList.get(position));
                        //Removing The Bowler From The List
                        bowlersList.remove(position);
                        mAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(position);
                        //db.leagueAverageScore(savedLeagueId);
                        toggleEmptyBowlers();
                    }
                });
        snackbar.show();
    }

    //Toggling List And Empty Bowler View
    private void toggleEmptyBowlers() {
        //You Can Check bowlerList.size() > 0

        if (db.getBowlersCount() > 0) {
            noBowlersView.setVisibility( View.GONE);
        } else {
            noBowlersView.setVisibility( View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRestart() {
        super.onRestart();
        //When BACK BUTTON is pressed, the activity on the stack is restarted
        //Do what you want on the refresh procedure here
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate( R.menu.menu_main, menu );
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, SettingsActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected( item );
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        //Check If Request Code Is The Same As What Is Passed - Here It Is 1
        if(requestCode==1)
        {
            String savedLeagueId=data.getStringExtra("seriesLeagueId");
            String seriesBowlerId=data.getStringExtra("seriesBowlerId");
            bowlersList.addAll(db.getAllBowlers(savedLeagueId));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class));
        finish();
        overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
    }
}
```

Bowler **Methods** in **DatabaseHelper.java**

```
public long insertBowler(String leagueId, String bowlerName, String bowlerAverage) {
    String bowlerHandicap ="0";

    //Get Writable Database That We Want To Write Data Too
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

    //`id` and `timestamp` Will Be Inserted Automatically
    values.put(Bowler.COLUMN_LEAGUE_ID, leagueId);
    values.put(Bowler.COLUMN_NAME, bowlerName);
    values.put(Bowler.COLUMN_BOWLER_AVERAGE, bowlerAverage);
    values.put(Bowler.COLUMN_BOWLER_HANDICAP, bowlerHandicap);

    //Insert Row
    //long id = db.insert(Bowler.TABLE_NAME, null, values);
    long id = db.insertOrThrow( Bowler.TABLE_NAME, null, values );
    Log.d("INSERTBOWLER","Number of bowlers in db = " + String.valueOf( DatabaseUtils.queryNumEntries(db,Bowler.TABLE_NAME)));
    //Close Database Connection
    db.close();

    //Return Newly Inserted Row Id
    return id;
}

public Bowler getBowler(String leagueId) {
    //Get Readable Database If We Are Not Inserting Anything
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor cursor = db.query( Bowler.TABLE_NAME,
            new String[]{Bowler.COLUMN_ID, Bowler.COLUMN_LEAGUE_ID, Bowler.COLUMN_NAME, Bowler.COLUMN_BOWLER_AVERAGE, Bowler.COLUMN_BOWLER_HANDICAP, Bowler.COLUMN_TIMESTAMP},
            Bowler.COLUMN_LEAGUE_ID + "=?",
            new String[]{String.valueOf(leagueId)}, null, null, null, null);

    Bowler bowler = null;
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {

        //Prepare Bowler Object
        bowler = new Bowler(
                cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(Bowler.COLUMN_ID)),
                cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Bowler.COLUMN_LEAGUE_ID)),
                cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Bowler.COLUMN_NAME)),
                cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Bowler.COLUMN_BOWLER_AVERAGE)),
                cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Bowler.COLUMN_BOWLER_HANDICAP)),
                cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Bowler.COLUMN_TIMESTAMP)));

        //Close Database Connection
        cursor.close();
        return bowler;
    } else {
        return bowler;
    }
}
public List<Bowler> getAllBowlers(String leagueId) {
    List<Bowler> bowlers = new ArrayList<>();

    //Select All Query
    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + Bowler.TABLE_NAME + " WHERE " + Bowler.COLUMN_LEAGUE_ID + " = '" + leagueId + "'" + " ORDER BY " +
            Bowler.COLUMN_TIMESTAMP + " DESC";

    Log.d("GETALLBOWLERS-SQL","SQL used = >>>>" +selectQuery + "<<<<");

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    Log.d("GETALLBOWLERS-CNT","Number of rows retrieved = " + String.valueOf(cursor.getCount()));


    //Looping Through All Rows And Adding To The List
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            Bowler bowler = new Bowler();
            bowler.setId(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(Bowler.COLUMN_ID)));
            bowler.setLeagueId(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Bowler.COLUMN_LEAGUE_ID)));
            bowler.setName(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Bowler.COLUMN_NAME)));
            bowler.setAverage(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Bowler.COLUMN_BOWLER_AVERAGE)));
            bowler.setHandicap(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Bowler.COLUMN_BOWLER_HANDICAP)));
            bowler.setTimestamp(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Bowler.COLUMN_TIMESTAMP)));
            bowlers.add(bowler);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    cursor.close();
    //Close Database Connection
    db.close();
    Log.d("GETALLBOWLERS-CNT","Number of elements in bowlerslist = " + String.valueOf(bowlers.size()));

    //Return Bowlers List
    return bowlers;
}

public int getBowlersCount() {
    String countQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + Bowler.TABLE_NAME;
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);

    int count = cursor.getCount();
    cursor.close();

    //Return The Count
    return count;
}

public int updateBowler(Bowler bowler) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(Bowler.COLUMN_LEAGUE_ID, bowler.getLeagueId());
    values.put(Bowler.COLUMN_NAME, bowler.getName());
    values.put(Bowler.COLUMN_BOWLER_AVERAGE, bowler.getAverage());

    //Updating Row
    return db.update(Bowler.TABLE_NAME, values, Bowler.COLUMN_ID + " = ?",
            new String[]{String.valueOf(bowler.getId())});
}

public void deleteBowler(Bowler bowler) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    db.delete( Bowler.TABLE_NAME, Bowler.COLUMN_ID + " = ?",
            new String[]{String.valueOf( bowler.getId())});
    db.close();
}
```

I am hoping that someone will be able to point out what I am doing incorrectly in order to fix this issue.

If any additional information is need please let me know and I will post it.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Try using `String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + Bowler.TABLE_NAME + " ORDER BY " +
            Bowler.COLUMN_TIMESTAMP + " DESC";`. If you still get **`D/GETALLBOWLERS-CNT: Number of rows retrieved = 0`**, then the bowlers table is empty. Otherwise (i.e. more than 0 rows retrieved) there is likely no bowler(s) with a league id of 1.

Comment: @Uiv the selectQuery above does show the bowlers table, but the problem is that not all bowlers belong to the same league. So by using this all bowlers show up in all the leagues.

Comment: Then if all bowlers are listed the issue must be with the WHERE clause not selecting bowlers with a league id of 1, as the WHERE clause itself looks fine (you could try `String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + Bowler.TABLE_NAME + " WHERE CAST(" + Bowler.COLUMN_LEAGUE_ID + " AS INTEGER) = CAST('" + leagueId + "' AS INTEGER)" + " ORDER BY " +
            Bowler.COLUMN_TIMESTAMP + " DESC";`);  Which would force the types for the comparison.If that results in 0 rows retrieved then you do not have any bowlers in the bowlers table where the leagueid is 1; the fix is to add rows.

Comment: @Uiv I replace the query string as you suggested but only the second league shows any bowlers, the first league with the id of 1 still doesn't show anything.  I put a image above showing this.  I believe the issue is that all the bowlers are getting an id of "2".

Comment: As you can see all the bowlers seem to have an id of 2,  I am not sure why this is. Also if I go back to the league with id 2 the new bowler I added in the first league appears, bowler 37

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out why all my new bowler entries have an id of **2**. In my edit Bowler Profile  Activity I have the following : `leagueId = String.valueOf(getIntent().getIntExtra("leagueId",2));`  The default value is 2 and because I was not grabbing the information being passed to the new Activity in the proper manner the app was always using **2** as the BowlerId.

I changed the code that was capturing the information from the intent to the following:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
        leagueId = intent.getStringExtra("leagueId");
```

With this change I was able to capture all the bowlers that belong to a particular league.  I only realized that I was passing the information incorrectly after reading through the following post:

[Pass a String from one Activity to another Activity in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6707900/pass-a-string-from-one-activity-to-another-activity-in-android)